# DRY-up `change` matcher expectations

Tags: rspec-rails

Is there any better way to DRY below `expectation`?

```
expect{ create(:counter) }.to change(Counter.count).by 1
expect{ create(:counter) }.to change(User.count).by 1
```

Below worked:

```
[Counter, User].each do |model|
  expect{ create(:counter) }.to change(model.count).by 1
end
```

Looking for the syntax like below(not working) :

```
expect{ create(:counter) }.to change(Counter && User, :count).by 1
```

using `Rails 3.1.6`, `rspec 2.6.4`